# Реализация многопоточного клиент-серверного приложения

Tags: python, python-3.x, клиент-сервер

Есть необходимость, как можно проще реализовать следую концепцию. Raspberry PI выступает как сервер и к GPIO подключён датчик. С ПК (выступающего в качестве клиента) даётся запрос на сервер для запуска считывание данных с датчика. Сервер в потоке начинает считывать данные датчика, но при этом параллельно продолжает слушать запросы адреса ПК. Как как только пользователь решает завершить считывание, он отправляет команду на остановку считывания. Сервер принимает запрос и прекращает работу датчика.

С помощью какого инструмента можно решить данную задачу? Смотрел в сторону SocketIO, но как мне кажется, есть более простые и понятные инструменты для решения данной задачи.

Comment: WebSockets? Вполне, я думаю. ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor только что наткнулся на статью про asyncio. Мне показалось, что разобраться в asyncio будет быстрее, чем в WebSockets. Как считаете?

Comment: Эээ... Ну дело в том, что asyncio _никак_ не связано с вашей задачей. Это просто асинхронное программирование (которое вам кстати понадобится для websockets BTW). ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor А чем отличается модуль socket от WebSockets?

Comment: Tcp vs WS... ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor А SocketIO это надстройка над WebSockets? И если да, то почему всё же лучше использовать WebSockets?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/498996/